# Pass value from activity to currently active fragment when EditTextvalue changed every time

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm making classified android application from 1 month I have stuck into a problem.
The scenario is as follows.

**I have one activity with a fragment showing ads on that fragment(Ads_display) like olx and in toolbar I have a city search fragment where user can changed the city it works perfectly fine first time when fragment is get create but after fragment is active the updated value of that textView (I'm taking value in textView from city search fragment) is not transferred to Ads_display fragment when i toast everytime it showing me the old city name which is passed at the time of fragment created**.Sorry in advance because I cannot paste my code snippet over here because Everyday I try something to do now situation is that I even dont understand what I have did.

Please help me out this situation with your valuable answers thanks in advanced.because I already reached my deadline.

Comment: You have to post some code man!, i can think of at least 10 different ways that can go wrong.

Comment: @KARAMJABER please if you please post your answer

Comment: @KARAMJABER any link any blog that may help as a walkthrough

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I think I have clearly explain my problem

Comment: @JeroenHeier I want to pass the updated textview value from Activity to currently activite fragment every time when the textview value get update

Comment: @KARAMJABER thank you for your kind help

Comment: @KARAMJABER I'll come back to you after implement it

Answer (score 1):

I would have down-voted this question but you seem in a tough spot.

first check how to pass data between fragments:

Here is what i would do:

```
 //Set the edit text on a changed listener
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Pass values from your fragment to your other fragment

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("city", s);

    FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();
    fragB.setArguments(b); 
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_container, fragB);

            }
        });





Then you have to receive your values in the fragment

    Bundle b = this.getArguments();
    if(b != null){
       String city = b.getString("city");
    }
```

if your value of search is from an activity then just pass the value from the activity to the fragment :

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(s, "city");
        tab1.setArguments(bundle);


            }
        });
```

Then get the arguments in your fragment

```
       if (getArguments() != null) {
            String city = getArguments().getString("city);
       }
```

or you can use an interface, i cannot see your code so i cannot say which is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must create interface as listener between the activity and fragment but I will suggest using EventBus it will make this approach easy for you

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus , http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/